# Evaluate Trigonometric Functions Using Only ln(x), exp(x) And Operators

Tags: trigonometry

Are there formulas for the common trigonometric functions (sin(x), cos(x), tan(x) etc) that can be expressed using just exp(x) and ln(x) and simple arithmetic (+, -, *, /)? I have to evaluate various trigonometric functions using a business programming library that for some odd reason does not support any trig functions but does support exp(x) and ln(x). Also, I can only do real arithmetic - no imaginary numbers.

Comment: With complex variables, yes.  Without, your best bet is to use a series approximation.

Comment: What's the program, out of curiosity?

Comment: What do you need to do _with_ the trigonometric functions, exactly? That might make a difference in how  you want to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

From a programming point of view, if speed and efficiency are of concern, I should use things like $$\sin(y)=\sin(x+a)=\sin (x)+a \cos (x)-\frac{a^2}{2}  \sin (x)-\frac{a^3}{6}  \cos (x)+\frac{a^4}{24}
    \sin (x)+\frac{a^5}{120}  \cos (x)-\frac{a^6}{720}  \sin (x)-\frac{a^7 }{5040}\cos
   (x)+\frac{a^8 }{40320}\sin (x)+\frac{a^9 }{362880}\cos (x)+O\left(a^{10}\right)$$ $$\cos(y)=\cos(x+a)=\cos (x)-a \sin (x)-\frac{a^2}{2}  \cos (x)+\frac{a^3}{6}  \sin (x)+\frac{a^4}{24}
    \cos (x)-\frac{a^5}{120}  \sin (x)-\frac{a^6}{720} \cos (x)+\frac{a^7 }{5040}\sin
   (x)+\frac{a^8 }{40320}\cos (x)-\frac{a^9 }{362880}\sin (x)+O\left(a^{10}\right)$$ (factor them) where $x$ would be the closest angle for which $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ have explicitely known values (see for example http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/simpleTrig.html#section1 for a quite detailed table).

Answer (score 0):

The only succinct equations I can think of for $\sin$ and $\cos$ are based on Euler's formula $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i \sin \theta$ but I can imagine this being really difficult in business software.  If it doesn't take trigonometric functions, I can hardly imagine it taking complex numbers.  The only other thing I can imagine would be to approximate the trigonometric functions using their Taylor expansions:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sin x & = & \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \\
\cos x & = & \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Find out what level of accuracy you need with your computations and truncate the series to a small polynomial.  Maybe 5 terms each would be a decent place to start your approximation?